# Solution of the differential equation of a pendulum with a block (air resistance)

Tags: classical-mechanics, drag, oscillators, differential-equations, non-linear-systems

The differential equation for a pendulum with air resistance is

$$
\ddot{y} + (b/m) \dot{y}^2+\frac{D}{m}y = 0
$$

What is a solution of the differential equation? I had problems to solve it.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that a differential equation can be solved analytically. I don’t know for sure that this one can’t be, but I doubt that it can. With linear rather than quadratic damping, it definitely can be.

Comment: Maybe the (second) method [here](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html) is applicable

Comment: As of now, there do not exist closed form solutions to this nonlinear differential equation. Most textbooks assume linear drag to avoid this issue and present a closed form analytic solution. However, as mentioned below, you can plug this into any software and get a numerical solution. If you massage the equation a bit, you should gain a little bit of intuition for the system in question though.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but maybe this paper could help [Finite Time Differential Equations](https://www.sci-hub.se/10.1109/CDC.1985.268832) (V. T. Haimo - 1985)

Answer (score 3):

There are (as far as I know) no closed form solutions, and certainly none tht are simple, to this differential equation. As @G.Smith points out, there is no reason to assume every differential equation has a closed form solution, and certainly not a non-linear equation like this one.

You may obtain a solution using something like [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5By%27%27%5Bt%5D+%2B+%5C%5BGamma%5D+y%27%5Bt%5D%5E2+%2B+%5C%5BDelta%5D+y%5Bt%5D+%3D%3D+0%2C+y%5Bt%5D%2C+t%5D), or integrate it numerically.

As @bolbteppa mentioned in the comment above, [there is a way](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html) to get $y'(t)$ as a function of $y(t)$. If this is what you're interested in, you can define $v = y'$ and rewrite your equation as $$v \frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}y} + \frac{b}{m}v^2 + \frac{D}{m}y =0 \quad \implies \quad \frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y} (v^2) + \frac{b}{m} v^2 = - \frac{D}{m} y,$$ which is a linear non-homogeneous first order differential equation in $v^2(y)$, and as such can be solved very easily using standard methods. This gives you $v$ as a function of $y$, but sadly can't be easily integrated to give either in terms of $t$!

Answer (score 1):

Tho solve the quadratically damped harmonic oscillator, you need two equations:

$$ \ddot y + \frac b m \dot y^2 + \frac D m = 0\ \ \ \ \dot y < 0 $$

$$ \ddot y - \frac b m \dot y^2 + \frac D m = 0\ \ \ \ \dot y > 0 $$

so that the damping force is always opposing the velocity.

A standard brute force method is to use a power series:

$$ y(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n $$
$$ \dot y(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}t^n$$
$$ \ddot y(t) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nt^{n-2} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}t^n$$

So you can try that.

A clever or novel method is worthy of publication, e.g.:
[image]

Comment: Good point, with the $\text{sign}(y)$ term this equation would become even harder to solve. Wouldn't the power series method be a real pain, though? Given that you'd have to square the series for $\dot{y}$?